# Checking the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ by limit test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For checking the convergence of a series, I will first check the limit of the general term: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{i/n}+e^{-i/n}}{2}=\frac{(1+1)}{2}=1$$ This means that the series 
 $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ diverges as the terms do not go to zero. Is this right, though?

Comment: You are right ;It diverges

Comment: but what happens if it would be $sin(1/n) $ the above procedure is right

Comment: yes sure it goes to zero

Comment: $cos(1/n^2)$ converges .

Comment: If it is $\sin(1/n)$ the series $\sum \sin (1/n)$ is divergent, as it is comparable to $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: it means the method i used above is wrong for sin(1/n)

Comment: @Boris $\cos (1/n^2)$ diverges , again as its nth term wont go to zero.

Comment: Would be better to show that series rather than letting us guess.

Comment: Note that you asked for convergence of the sequence $\cos/frac{1}{n}$ but at the end of the question you are discussing about the convergence of  its Series. Its confusing

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this sort of limit is to use continuity. Note that the limit of the sequence is the same as the limit of the corresponding function (assuming the latter limit exists):
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\tfrac1n) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(\tfrac1x).
$$
Now we know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x = 0$, and that $\cos(u)$ is continuous at $u=0$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(\tfrac1x) = \cos\big( \lim_{x\to\infty} \tfrac1x \big) = \cos 0 = 1.
$$

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the critiques implied by the downvotes.

Comment: Maybe you got the downvote because the user asked for the series $\sum \cos \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative but equivalent way of writing Greg Martin's approach:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(\tfrac1x) 
$$
By limit substitution, this is equivalent to computing:
$$
\lim_{\frac{1}{x}\to 0} \cos(\tfrac1x) 
$$
And now by continuity of  the function $\cos(x)$ we get that: 
$$
\lim_{\frac{1}{x}\to 0} \cos(\tfrac1x)=\cos(0)=1  
$$

Since the general term does not go to $0$ in the limit, we conclude that by the limit test the series $\sum \cos(\frac{1}{n})$ diverges.